# Subscribing to iframe body content using Observables in Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to subscribe to the content of an iframe to check if the body is empty?

Something like this:

```
const frame = document.getElementById('frame');
Observable.of(frame).subscribe(el => 'check if body is empty here');
```